# How to get data that is already present in input.txt file and find the highest salary using a dictionary C#

Tags: c#, file, dictionary

**Highest Salary in Dept**

I have to read data from given below data from input file

The input is being read in from a file called input.txt in this format:

```
22,Rajan Anand,Engineering,1600000
23,Swati Patil,Testing,800000
27,Vijay Chawda,Engineering,800000
29,Basant Mahapatra,Engineering,600000
32,Ajay Patel,Testing,350000
34,Swaraj Birla,Testing,350000
```

Each line consists of 4 fields

```
"Employee ID," "Name," "Department," and "Salary."
```

Here, "Employee ID" and "Salary" are integers, while "Name" and "Department" are strings that do not contain commas or newlines.

Currently, below program reads the input and creates an array of String from the lines of input. Then it calls a method processData on with this array, and prints the returned data to the output file.

Unfortunately, processData currently does not do anything useful - it just returns an empty `Dictionary<String,int>`.

I have to modify processData find the Employee IDs of the highest paid employee in each department. Specifically, processData should return a dictionary where each key is the name of a department,and the value is the Employee ID of the employee in that department who has the highest salary.

In case multiple employees in a department are tied for the highest salary, you can pick any one of them.

```
Engineering: 22
Testing: 23
```

Sample program

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;

namespace ProgramNamespace
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static Dictionary<String, int> processData(IEnumerable<string> lines)
        {
            Dictionary<String, int> retVal = new Dictionary<String, int>();
            return retVal;
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try 
            {
                 Dictionary<String, int> retVal = processData(File.ReadAllLines("input.txt")); 
                 // code to write in output file
            }
            catch (IOException ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Vishal and welcome to stackoverflow. I've fixed the formatting of your original question. Please take the time to learn about how to properly format your question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). A well-formatted question is always more likely to attract answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could do it as following if you want to do it with `Dictionary<string,int>`. the Crux of idea is to create an intermediate list comprising of all Employees and then Group them by Department, before Ordering By Salary(desc) and taking the first one.

```
public static Dictionary<String, int> processData(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
        Dictionary<String, int> retVal = new Dictionary<String, int>();
        var list = new List<Employee>();
        foreach(var user in lines)
        {
            var userDetails = user.Split(new []{','},StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            list.Add(new Employee
            {
            Id=int.Parse(userDetails[0]),   
            UserName = userDetails[1],
            Department = userDetails[2],
            Salary = int.Parse(userDetails[3])
            });
       }

        retVal = list.GroupBy(x=>x.Department).Select(x=>x.ToList()
                     .OrderByDescending(c=>c.Salary).First())
                     .ToDictionary(x=> x.Department, y=> y.Id);
        return retVal;
 }
```

Where Employee is defined as

```
public class Employee
{
    public int Id;
    public string UserName;
    public int Salary;
    public string Department;

}
```

Output

[image]

Comment: Hello @Anu Viswan I did the changes as per above code, however its giving me error message in main method that "The name 'ProcessData' does not exist in current context"

Comment: @VishalSuravase Could you share your code.ProcessData doesn't look to be in the current scope, so would like to see your code.

Comment: Thank you @Anu Viswan your solution worked. I messed up with curly braces due to which the scope was lost. Thanks once again

Comment: @IanKemp Sure Ian, will take care from next time

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea:

1. create an Class name "EmployeeSalary"(or other name you like)
2. parse all lines into List< EmployeeSalary > (use split, and create new object)
3. use linq to query List< EmployeeSalary >(group by department and find max salary)
4. generate query result to dictionary you want.

If you are familiar with linq, that would be much easier to get the idea.

```
public Dictionary<String, int> processData(IEnumerable<string> lines)
{
    List<EmployeeSalary> list = new List<EmployeeSalary>();
    foreach(var line in lines)
    {
        string[] temp = line.Split(',');
        EmployeeSalary tempObj = new EmployeeSalary();
        tempObj.EmployeeID = int.Parse(temp[0]);
        tempObj.Name = temp[1];
        tempObj.Department = temp[2];
        tempObj.Salary = int.Parse(temp[3]);
        list.Add(tempObj);
    }

    var query = (from f in list group f by f.Department into g select g);
    Dictionary<String, int> retVal  = 
    query.ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.OrderByDescending(c=>c.Salary).Select(c=>c.EmployeeID).FirstOrDefault());

    return retVal;
}
```

Comment: thank you charles this really helps i will try executing this solution

Comment: @VishalSuravase I dont't know if this answer is helpful but still have someone vote down my answer, please help to vote, thanks!

Comment: @charleschen I downvoted your answer because you are giving a full solution to someone who has not made any effort on their part. That is not what Stack Overflow is for, and you should not encourage people to misuse it in this way.

Comment: @IanKemp I think it's not fair, maybe I can remove the code from my answer and only left the thinking of solution (point1~4). If you think the question is homework, you should vote down the question rather than my answer.

Comment: @IanKemp even though it's homework, I think we can provide the thinking guide to them. (not directly the code). That's how statckoverflow works. I never encourage people to misuse it.

Comment: @Ian Kemp you assumed that the one who is posting his/her question did nothing on their own. this really makes sense isn't it? You could have ignored this question instead of comenting

Comment: @VishalSuravase Since you didn't supply anything showing you made a effort, the only conclusion I can draw is that you didn't. And questions that don't show effort are off-topic for Stack Overflow. Those are the rules.